# Regex to find exact match based on middle of a string

Tags: regex, shell, perl

Trying to file single file based on a string before the date. File named as follows;
All begin with DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS*  then identifier .DHT or *BNT, then timestamp.TXT

```
DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS.DHT.2019-07-22-210004.TXT
DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS.BNT.2019-04-23-190824.TXT
```

Tried as follows

```
/(?:DHT\.BENT\.RSEC\.ETNS\.DHT)(?:.*).TXT/
/(?:DHT\.BENT\.RSEC\.ETNS\.BNT)(?:.*).TXT/
```

I expect each to give me the code individual line on full string match

```
DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS.DHT.2019-07-22-210004.TXT
DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS.BNT.2019-04-23-190824.TXT
```

.   Need help to improve the regex

Comment: I am assuming you want to capture the second group, but your are setting it to non-capture with the `?:`. You want the second group as `(.*)`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable example that shows the problem

Comment: I don't understand what you want your regular expression to do for you. Which part of the string do you want to match and/or extract exactly?

Comment: The regex both work. The problem is elsewhere in your program.

Comment: I am trying to match the DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS.DHT.2019-07-22-210004.TXT full match but must have  middle *(DNT)* or should be the first group to match on this particular string and return a full match for (DHT.BENT.RSEC.ETNS. DHT.2019-07-22-210004.TXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expression seems to be just fine, maybe we would include some more constraints, if that'd be OK, such as:

```
^(?:DHT\.BENT\.RSEC\.ETNS\.DHT)\.\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d+\.TXT$
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/IM8QhI/1)

Or:

```
^(?:DHT\.BENT\.RSEC\.ETNS\.BNT)\.\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d+\.TXT$
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/wzTWdj/1)

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wzTWdj/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/wzTWdj/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]